# NotFoundHttpException on every route with nginx

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, nginx

I try to configure nginx to handle all /{{app}}/query requests dynamically to laravel applications like this:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;
    root   /usr/share/nginx/apps;

    location / {
        index index.php;
        try_files $uri @rewriteapp;
    }

    location @rewriteapp {
        rewrite ^/([^/]+)(.*)$ /$1/public/index.php?$2 last;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Currently nginx routes my requests to the correct directory and file. For example:

```
www.domain.com/test/item/1/edit
```

... routes to:

```
/path/to/my/apps/test/public/index.php?/item/1/edit
```

I'm also able to echo out var_export($_GET) and see that query:

```
array(
    '/item/1/edit' => '',
)
```

But Laravel allways says:

```
NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:
in RouteCollection.php line 161
at RouteCollection->match(object(Request)) in Router.php line 823
at Router->findRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 691
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 675
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 246
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 52
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 44
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(CheckForMaintenanceMode), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 136
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 102
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 132
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 99
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 57
```

But why?

The routes looks like this:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('/item', function() {
    return 'Item';
});
```

php artisan route:list returns:

```
+--------+----------+---------+------+---------+------------+
| Domain | Method   | URI     | Name | Action  | Middleware |
+--------+----------+---------+------+---------+------------+
|        | GET|HEAD | /       |      | Closure | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD | item    |      | Closure | web        |
+--------+----------+---------+------+---------+------------+
```

My Laravel Version is 5.2.33
I use Ubuntu 16.04 Server with PHP 7.0.6 (PHP-FPM) as Host.

Is it a nginx config issue? 
Or a Laravel issue? 
Or is it a Linux, maybe permission related topic?

Comment: You're getting a not found exception because `item/1/edit` really doesn't exist in your routes. Does `/item` work?

Comment: Nope. I can define whatever route usually works in Laravel with a standard Nginx configuration. In this case neither /, /item nor /item/{id}/edit works.

Comment: Is each application the same just different instances (eg, multi-tenant). Or is each app completely different? Basically what is your reasoning behind using $1 like that in the nginx config?

Comment: Each are completely different. The reason to try it this way is to deal multiple laravel applications with a single nginx configuration I don't have to change afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Point application root to public folder and it will work

Comment: What root path do you mean? I found no Laravel constant for a root path. Its not APP_URL, right?

Comment: Have you set your app root to /public folder? Because index.php is in it.

Comment: Try to access path as www.example.com/public/your_route

Comment: www.domain.com/test/public/item/1/edit works :)

I thought that nginx already routes the request to the public directory as I rewrite the requests to it.

Comment: That is what i am trying to say that you need to point to public folder. If you want to use it like normal. Otherwise you can access the routes with public

Comment: Thank you very much. That's exactly what I don't understand yet. Because Nginx already calls the public directory. Otherwise I wouldn't see anything from laravel.

Answer (score 0):

I found following solution, after some research and trying:

```
server {

    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    location = / {

        # redirect if no app is specified
        return 301 http://www.domain.com; 
    }

    location ~* ^/([^/]+)(.*)\.(jpe?g|png|svg|gif|ico|doc|docx|xls|xlsx|pdf|txt)$ {

        # handle static files
        alias /usr/share/nginx/apps/$1/public$2.$3;
    }

    location ~* ^/([^/]+)(.*)$ {

        # handle laravel requests
        root /usr/share/nginx/apps/$1/public;

        try_files /index.php =404;

        include         fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_param   REQUEST_URI  $2;
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root/index.php;
    }
}
```